# BufferedReader `is.ready()` method not working properyly

Tags: java, io

```
try {
        Scanner inConsole = new Scanner(System.in);
        String CONNECT_TO_WHOM = "";
        Socket clientEndPoint = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientEndPoint.getOutputStream(), true);                   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientEndPoint.getInputStream()));

        MessageFromServerThread messageFromServer = new MessageFromServerThread(in);
        messageFromServer.start();

        // Giving Client Details To whom To Connect 
        if(!in.ready())
        CONNECT_TO_WHOM = inConsole.nextLine();

        //System.out.println("You are Connecting To This " + CONNECT_TO_WHOM);
        out.println(CONNECT_TO_WHOM);
        //break;

        System.out.println("To quit press q");
        //inConsole.nextLine();
        while(!clientMessage.equals("q")) {
                out.println(clientMessage = inConsole.nextLine());
                //System.out.println(in.readLine());  
        }
        System.out.println("Check in chatClient");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code working flow:
Whenever client gets connected it the server, server will inform the client about all the other available clients, Then the from the client, server expects to which client to connect. 
Here, there is a possibility that the client can be connected to another client before he wants to communicate with others. In that case the server informs that you are connected to Client X. I want to check this incident occurrence, via the `if(!in.ready())`.

I do understand that the `in` buffer could very well be empty. any way to effectively do this checking.

Comment: What is the underlying input of `in`? And what does 'somehow it is not working in my code' mean? Where is your evidence that the method is not working properly?

Comment: And what's the question now?

Comment: I Figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The java.io.BufferedReader.ready() method informs whether the stream
>   is ready to be read. A buffered character stream is only ready when
>   the buffer is not empty or if the underlying stream is ready.

So your buffer should be empty to make it return `false` condition